# Simulate autocorrelated variable based on data in R

Tags: r, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, simulation

I am trying to simulate data for a longitudinal multilevel model. Let's say I want to simulate 4 observations of random variable X for N persons - how would I do that assuming autocorrelation of X to some extend (meaning, values of X should be more similar between t1 and t2 than between t1 and t4). I have observed values of X for 1000 persons (at one time point) and I would like to base my simulation on this empirical variable (which is pretty skewed).

If I wasn't looking for autocorrelation of X, I'd just use `sample(X, N, replace = T)`.

Comment: Without a probabilistic model, you cannot run a simulation experiment.

Comment: Could you expand on that? Do you mean there is a problem with not assuming a distribution of X but bootstrapping from an existing variable?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean: to use bootstrap, you need to recover an iid structure in order to sample with replacement. This means assuming a particular dependence configuration for the observed data, as eg an AR model.

Comment: I'd like to know how to specify an AR model (as described above: 4 measurement occasions for N persons) and simulate data from it. Using the existing cross-sectional data to do this is just optional, if bootstrapping is a problem, I'd settle for a variable with e.g. a known normal or uniform distribution.